# Changing To Retrieve Data in Real Time

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, real-time-data

in this code I am able to retrieve data from Firestore once after I starts to run this page. Is it possible to make it run in real time where it will be able to get all the data from Firestore in real time?

```
Future getMarker() async{
    Firestore.instance.collection('markers').getDocuments().then((myData){
      if(myData.documents.isNotEmpty){
        for (int i = 0; i < myData.documents.length; i++){
          initMarker(myData.documents[i].data, myData.documents[i].documentID);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

When i change the `getDocuments()` to `snapshots()` then method `then()` will give out an error stated that `then()` is not a Stream type. Or is there any approach to this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes), one option is to use the [`listen`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-async/Stream/listen.html) method of the `Stream` returned by the [`snapshots()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/snapshots.html) method.

The doc also shows an example with another option: using a [`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) which "helps automatically manage the streams state and disposal of the stream when it's no longer used within your app".

Comment: Thank you for the documentation. I have 1 more question. Is it possible to get the same functionality (retrieve data in real-time) without using a 'StreamBuilder'? Is there any alternative? or is there other documentation regarding this. Thank you so much for your kind answer.

Comment: Yes, you can use the `listen` method as mentioned at the top of the answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942707/flutter-firestore-listen-for-document-changes